# how to control send speed of mongo db stream?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to stream oplog from mongoDB.

```
oplog.stream = coll.find(query, options).sort({
     ts: 1
 }).batchSize(blockSize).stream();
```

Can I specify wait time between batches to slow down its speed?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution at nodejs v0.10's stream documents

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume

resume, pause and pipe

Comment: Hi, I use the pause technic with setTimeout 1ms but this brings the number to less than 800 per second. So it's either too fast like 15000 up or too slow like less than 1000, did you find a solution to have it under control? tnx

Comment: Hi finally what you found? which technique is more suitable for you...?

Comment: Note: also can keep a count for each stream, reset the counter to 0 as required